# Extract human sound from a wav file using java

Tags: java, algorithm, signals, javasound

I am working on a project where I have to extract the human sound from a audio .wav file using java.

The audio .wav file may have 3 to 4 sounds like dog, cat, music and human. I will have to identify the human sound then exatract that part from the audio .wav file.

I am using [FFT.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/97data/FFT.java.html) and [Complex.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/97data/Complex.java.html).

Now I have written an AudioFileReader class which reads the audio.wav file from the hard-drive and then convert this to bytes array. Then used the above mentioned FFT.java and Complex.java to apply FFT.fft(bytesArray), which gives me Complex array in return;

Now the problem is how to extract the human sound byte pattern from the returned Complex array... does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this?

---

Edit: We are assuming a very simple audio.wav file. For example, cat sound then silence, human sound then silence, dog sound then silence etc. No mixture of voices.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I am struggling with the project to finish but still no success. I need some help to extract the human sound from the wav file using java but stuck till now.

Comment: I'm curious whether you will also be able to extract sound of a human imitating a cat. And what about a parrot imitating a human imitating a cat?

Comment: I am not considering the sound of human imitating to a cat or dog etc. As I have already explained that I will only consider a very simple file containing different sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I think the standard way to handle problems like this are to convert the input signals into a Cepstrum or Mel-Cepstrum representation and then use the coefficients for the feature space for input into a classifier. There are many research papers that discuss solutions to these sorts of problems based on this basic approach, for example:

http://www.ics.forth.gr/netlab/data/J17.pdf

One possible shortcut you might try would be to put the input signals through a low bit-rate vocoder such as AMBE, then decode, and compare the quality of the original signal to the encoded/decoded signal. These vocoders are designed to highly compress human speech with fair to good quality at the expense of not being able to adequately represent non-speech sounds.

Comment: I agree. I have seen such an implementation that was even able to distinguish between spoken voice and music. So I assume that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by AI (and little short of that).  You might investigate APIs for speech recognition, but I doubt their ability to support signals with noise in the background.

E.G.

- Is that a cat, or someone saying 'meow'?
- Is that music, or someone singing 'do, re, mi..'?
- Who said 'Polly wanna cracker', the *human or the parrot?*

Comment: We are assuming a very simple audio.wav file. For example, cat sound then silence, human sound then silence, dog sound then silence etc. No mixture of voices.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a classic AI problem (machine learning/pattern recognition) Have a look at [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_%28machine_learning%29)

But basically you'll need already classified data that you feed into your algorithm so that it can learn how to classify new data. But beware, 100% correctness is something that's illusive for almost anything in this field, although for your simple problem it could be possible (depends on your exact definition of the problem)